# Partition of Symmetric Group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

For symmetric group $S_n$, we need to find a collection of subgroups $G_i$'s such that union of these subgroups is the group $S_n$ and each subgroup found is isomorphic to direct product of cyclic groups, each of order more than 1.

How can we find these subgroups such that sum of sizes of the subgroup is not much more than $S_n$ i.e. $(1 + o_n(1))\cdot|S_n|$?

Comment: What do you mean by cover? You mean they should generate it, or their union should be the entire group?

Comment: If $n$ is a prime, I don't see where there is a subgroup containing an $n$-cycle and being a product of two or more cyclic groups.

Comment: Their union should be the entire group. @Gerry: If not for all n, does it happen for some particular n?

Comment: Maybe if you explained what made you ask this question?

Comment: I don't know. It's not clear to me that you can get the $n$-cycles, even if $n$ is not prime.

Comment: I want to analyze lifts of graphs(each vertex replaced by n vertices and each edge replaced by a matching between two sets of n vertices). When the permutation(matchings) is arbitrary analysis becomes difficult but if they form nice subgroups, analysis is much easier. So, I wanted to partition the symmetric group into these subgroups(don't need to know the exact subgroups, just the fact that they exists suffice)

Comment: One might also pose the following re-imagining of the situation: let $\Gamma_n$ be the set of all collections $\cal A$ of nontrivial abelian subgroups of $S_n$ such that $\bigcup{\cal A}=S_n$, define a function $f:\Gamma_n\to{\bf N}$ given by $f({\cal A}):=\sum_{A\in{\cal A}}\#A$, and define $\xi(n):=\min_{{\cal A}\in\Gamma_n}f({\cal A})$: now we may ask about the growth rate of $\xi(n)$ (or equivalently of $\xi(n)/n!$). This approach has the potential flaw of not necessarily capturing the structure or pattern behind minimal examples that may exist.

Comment: I was using $\varepsilon_n$ to represent that it is small but now changed it to $o_n(1)$ which can be any function going to zero as n tends to infinity.